# Iterate through XML to get all child nodes text value

Tags: python, xml-parsing

i have a xml with following data. i need to get value of  and all other attribute. i return a python code there i get only first driver value.

My xml :

```
<volume name="sp" type="span" operation="create">
    <driver>HDD1</driver>
    <driver>HDD2</driver>
    <driver>HDD3</driver>
    <driver>HDD4</driver>
</volume>
```

My script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.parse("vol.xml")
root = doc.getroot() #Returns the root element for this tree.
root.keys()          #Returns the elements attribute names as a list. The names are returned in an arbitrary order
root.attrib["name"]
root.attrib["type"]
root.attrib["operation"]

print root.get("name")
print root.get("type")
print root.get("operation")

for child in root:
    #print child.tag, child.attrib
    print root[0].text
```

My output:

```
    sr-query:~# python volume_check.py aaa
    sp
    span
    create
    HDD1
   sr-queryC:~#
```

I am not get `HDD2`, `HDD3` and `HDD4`. How to itirate through this xml to get all values? Any optimized way? I think any for loop can do that but not familiar with Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `for` loop, it should be

```
child.text
```

not

```
root[0].text
```